# Python OpenCV multiple UDP streams. Huge Latency and drop rate

Tags: python, opencv, udp, video-streaming

I'm streaming multiple UDP streams using ffmpeg from one device, there's also a concurrent process for each stream that calculates a score for each frame and sends the score on another port. On the receiving side, the client is reading a frame and a score for each stream and displaying the frame from the stream that has the best score.

The problem is, if there are multiple streams, the receiver starts to become extremely laggy and drops so many frames, even weirder, it's worse at lower bitrates (at 200kpbs and 4 video streams, about 40% of frames dropped and ~10s delay).

To rule out a network problem, I tried just displaying all the streams on the client side in different processes (each process reads and displays one stream). This way, there was minimal latency and drop. It seems like having multiple VideoCaptures in the same process is somehow slowing it down.

Here is the relevant part of the client code.

```
# thread per stream, reads frames and queues them up
def rx_thread(ip, vport, tport, q):
    global die
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((ip, tport))
    reader = s.makefile('r')
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('udp://'+ip+':'+str(vport))
    while not die:
        score = float(reader.readline())
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            die = True
            break
        q.put((frame, score))
    cap.release()
    reader.close()
    s.close()

output = open(argv[1], 'w', buffering=1)

# arg[3] .. are pairs of video port and score port
queues = []
for i in range(3, len(argv), 2):
    q = queue.Queue(30)
    t = threading.Thread(target=rx_thread,
            args=(argv[2], int(argv[i]),int(argv[i+1]), q))
    t.start()
    queues.append(q)

frames_count = 0
start = None

while True:
    try:
        frames, info = zip(*map(lambda q: q.get(True, 5), queues))
    except queue.Empty:
        die = True
        break

    if start is None:
        start = time()
        output.write('start: %.3f\n' % start)

    frames_count += 1

    # get stream with max score and show
    index = info.index(max(info))
    cv2.imshow('Video', frames[index])


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        die = True
        break

output.write('frames_count: %d\n' % frames_count)
```

**Edit**:

A few suggested it might have to do with how scores are sent. I tried completely ignoring the scores (I don't open the scores socket, and I'm putting a dummy score of 1.0 for each frame as I enqueue it). So basically, the client is just reading a bunch of video streams. The problem still persists. At the start, there is always a bunch of errors like these:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ff838016fc0] Error, header damaged or not MPEG-4 header (f_code=0)
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ff838016fc0] header damaged
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ff838046c40] warning: first frame is no keyframe
[mpeg4 @ 0x7ff840016f80] Error, header damaged or not MPEG-4 header (qscale=0)
```

The `first frame is no keyframe` error seems to happen exactly n-1 times when the number of streams is n.

Comment: what keeps the video frames in sync with the scores?  also why not use TCP if you're treating the socket like that?

Comment: Currently, nothing. I thought, I'll take care of that later. Could that be the cause of the issue? The scores are sent each in separate frames. I'll try to verify if that's  the cause.

Comment: @nathancy I'm already polling frames from each stream in separate threads

Answer (score -1):

at a guess it's to do with how you're sending the scores.  UDP isn't a reliable stream protocol and telling Python to pretend it is via `s.makefile()` is a **very** [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction).  I can replicate something similar by having a client and server do:

```
def receiver():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
        sock.bind(('', 8888))
        with sock.makefile('r') as reader:
            print('receiver running')
            while True:
                print('received', repr(reader.readline()))


def sender():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
        sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
        with sock.makefile('w') as writer:
            for i in range(1000):
                print('sending', i)
                print('value =', i, 'stuff to fill the buffers up', file=writer)
                time.sleep(0.02)
```

and running them at the same time.  you'll see the sender "sending" values regularly, but the receiver will receive them in blocks as they happen to get flushed

I'm guessing the reason behaviour becomes worse when things are slower is because the scores will be pushed less regularly, due to buffers filling up more slowly

in general you're much better off using `send` and `recv` directly on the sockets, which gives you more control over buffering and packet boundaries.  also note that UDP is not reliable, and hence it's free to drop and reorder packets.  you therefore need something in there to keep track of everything, maybe asking the scoring service to retry sending scores if some weren't received in time